# Pochette vs portefeuille vs sac à main

Tags: vocabulaire

Salut, j'essaye de trouver la difference entre les trois objets du titre.

Voici ce que je pense que c'est

1. Pochette - portefeuille des femmes?
2. portefeuille - "wallet" des hommes (aussi des femmes)?

[image]

3. sac à main - un grand sac des femmes

[image]

Pouvez-vous m'aider? Merci!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Le *sac à main* est un sac (pas nécessairement grand) qui sert à transporter clés, lunettes, papiers, portefeuile, portemonnaie, téléphone, maquillage, mouchoirs, etc. Il est muni d'une ou deux bandoulières ou anses, et se porte soit à la main (tenu alors par le(s) lanière(s)), soit à l'épaule. Le *sac à main* est un accessoire féminin, mais on peut trouver des équivalents masculins qu'on appellera plutôt *sac à bandoulière*.
- Le *portefeuille* était à l'origine un accessoire typiquement masculin, mais aujourd'hui il est utilisé indifférement par les deux sexes (bien qu'on trouve des modèles plutôt féminins ou plutôt masculins). Il se plie souvent en deux et permet de ranger des billets de banque, de pièces de monnaie, des cartes de banque et des documents d'identité. Il est assez petit pour se porter dans la poche d'un pantalon (pour les hommes) ou dans un sac à main (pour les dames).
- La *pochette* est un étui qui se porte à la main (ou parfois au poignet, grâce à une petite bandoulière). Typiquement, il remplace le sac à main des dames pour être porté avec une tenue de soirée. C'est un accessoire féminin, mais on peut aussi trouver des modèles pour hommes (il me semble que c'était à la mode dans les années 1970/1980, mais c'est aujourd'hui assez rare, et également appelé *sacoche*).[image]
- On peut aussi citer le *portemonnaie*, qui ressemble au portefeuille mais qui est plutôt un sac ou étui de plus petites dimensions, et qui est destiné à ranger principalement des pièces de monnaie (mais rien n'empêche son utilisateur d'y glisser quelques billets pliés ou une carte de banque si la place le permet). Il est aussi utilisé par les deux sexes, et il existe aussi des modèles plutôt féminins ou masculins.

Comment: Dans les années 70, 80, c'était les sacoches qui étaient à la mode pour les hommes. Une pochette, c'est plutôt un mouchoir qui dépasse de la poche haute d'une veste.

Comment: J'ai en tête une "pochette" comme ici: http://philippe-serres.com/homme/48-148-pochette.html. Pour moi, une sacoche est plus grande qu'une pochette (qui n'a assez d'espace que pour un portefeuille, un téléphone, des lunettes p.ex. et qui tient dans la main) - mais je me demande s'il n'y a pas des usages régionaux différents  sur ce point (p. ex. *sacoche* est aussi synonyme de sac à main en Belgique et au Québec). On peut aussi citer un accessoire plus récent qui est la *pochette* pour tablette ou petit ordinateur portable (en fait une sorte de housse).

Comment: Oui, le lien représente ce qu'on appelait chez moi une sacoche.

Comment: J'ai ajouté l'usage de *sacoche* dans ce sens à la réponse;

Comment: Merci pour l'explication détaillée!!!